# CSS - Add padding to second line of inline text

Tags: css

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but I figured it was worth asking.

It would be pointless me trying to explain, I'm rubbish at things like that, so check out this demo - http://www.deanelliott.me/braintrain/

See how the titles on the 6 images have an orange background colour? And now see how the padding is missing from the right hand side of the first, and left hand side of the second line?

Is it possible to add padding there so that the background doesn't just stop at the end/beginning of the word?

Or should I tell them it's unfeasable and they'll have to live with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is you can't pad at word end/start where the content wraps, so this won't be possible unless you change the display type for the links to a block-style type, e.g. "block" or "inline-block", but naturally that affects the appearance somewhat.

You can get slightly further by adding:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

to the `.blog-grid .grid-block h2 a, #sidebar h2 a` rule; however it's not a complete solution (but it's all I can come up with).

Comment: I think this is probably the best solution. They'll just have to live with it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

```
.blog-grid .grid-block h2 a, #sidebar h2 a {
    /* other css properties */
    display: inline-block; /* or display: block */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding text-indent in CSS can also work

```
text-indent: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

add some code to class "post-title tilt" - it answeirs for your titles.
write maybe `padding-left:20px;` or if it won't work:   `margin-left:20px;`

Answer (score -3):

can you edit the code? adding span for each line should work
span class="line1" and span class="line2"

```
<a href="#">
  <span class="line1">a safe alternative to</span>
  <span class="line2">ritalin</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I can't, it will be a Wordpress post title

Comment: http://englishmike.net/wordpress/2008/06/04/wordpress-quick-tips-1-embedding-html-in-post-titles/